# Scala Lift Servlets within WebServer compilation

Tags: java, scala, webserver, jetty, lift

I want to learn Scala and do it on real project. This project needs logic to be wrapped within web server. So I made some tests with embedded Jetty and I like it. It is time for making next step to Scala. I am interesting what combination below you'll recommend me?

1) Embedded Jetty + Java Servlets + Scala;

In this combination I can bake "main" web server within Java code and use Servlets for web requests/responses; And Core project's logic can be written on Scala and then can be imported into "main" web server logic as Java package;

2) Embedded Jetty + Lift + Scala;

Do not write Java code, but write all "main" web server logic on Scala with Lift framework; Core project's logic can be still written on Scala;

**What advantages of each combination do you see?**

Thank you for any advice!!!;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old post, and you might have already decided which way to go, but here are a few things I can point out.

1. Today's web applications have so many things to do such as database access, session management, integration with the client side program using Ajax and so on. In that sense, #1 doesn't help much. You would need to write a lot of code from scratch.
2. I personally like Lift a lot. Though, its unique features and concepts might confuse you especially when you're new to Scala.
3. There are other alternatives raging from ones in the Scala world such as Scalatra and Play to ones in the Java world such as Spring.

I hope this will help,

KK